# Динамическая замена данных по выбору из select

Tags: javascript, объекты, html-select

Друзья, нужна помощь специалистов!

Итак, есть у меня несколько выпадающих списков, которые сделаны через `select`:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="cell4 cell1">
  <select name="Gender" class="sum2 sum3">
    <option value="X">All</option>
    <option value="0">Male</option>
    <option value="1">Female</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td class="cell4 cell1">
  <select name="Social status" class="sum2 sum3">
     <option value="X">All</option>
     <option value="1">Free</option>
     <option value="0">Slave</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td class="cell4 cell1">
  <select name="Adult" class="sum2 sum3">
     <option value="X">All</option>
     <option value="1">Adult</option>
     <option value="0">Children</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td class="cell4 cell1">
  <span id="qualityTotal"></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

а есть у меня обьект, который содержит в себе данные:

```
const ADULT_YES = 1,
      ADULT_NO = 0;

const WORK_YES = 1,
      WORK_NO = 0;

const MEN = 0,
      FEMALE = 1;
      //ALL = X;

const SLAVE = 0,
      FREE = 1,
      ALL_SOC = 2;

let summary = {
  'TOTAL': 1,

  [`${MEN}`]:0,//0
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}`]:0,//00
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_YES}`]:0,//001
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_NO}`]:0,//000
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_YES}${WORK_YES}`]:0,//0011
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_YES}${WORK_NO}`]:0,//0010
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_NO}${WORK_YES}`]:0,//0001
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_NO}${WORK_NO}`]:0,//0000
  [`${MEN}${FREE}`]:0,//01
  [`${MEN}${FREE}${ADULT_YES}`]:0,//011
  [`${MEN}${FREE}${ADULT_NO}`]:0,//010
  [`${MEN}${FREE}${ADULT_YES}${WORK_YES}`]:0,//0111
  [`${MEN}${FREE}${ADULT_YES}${WORK_NO}`]:0,//0110
  [`${MEN}${FREE}${ADULT_NO}${WORK_YES}`]:0,//0101
  [`${MEN}${FREE}${ADULT_NO}${WORK_NO}`]:0,//0100

  [`${ALL}${ALL}${ALL}${ALL}`]: 0,

};
```

И вот какая задача: как сделать так, чтобы в `<span id="qualityTotal"></span>` автоматически выводилось содержимое конкретного параметра обьекта, когда меняется выбор в `select`, чтобы получалось что-то вроде такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там где красная 10 должно выводиться количество из summary в соотвествии выборов `select`-элементов без каких-либо дополнительных телодвижений.

По идее вывод в `<span id="qualityTotal"></span>` должен иметь какой-то такой вид:

```
let gen = document.querySelector('[name="Gender"]').value
let soc = document.querySelector('[name="Social status"]').value
let adult = document.querySelector('[name="Adult"]').value

document.querySelector('qualityTotal').innerHTML = summary[`${gen}${soc}${adult}${WORK_NO}`]
```

Здесь значения `value` совпадают с константами в `summary`, таким образом, я могу выбрать конкретный тип данных, но как это сделать автоматическим я ума не приложу.

Кроме того, есть еще одна проблема, которая касается параметра `ALL`, то есть я не представляю, как призвести вывод лишь по одному параметру, а не всем трем. Например, мне нужно выбрать только мужчин, без учета их социального статуса или возраста... Как это можно реализовать в данном примере?
Вот пример того, что я имею ввиду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По идее здесь идет обращение к `['${MEN}${WORK_NO}']:0,`, то есть мне нужно учесть все возможные варианты в `${soc}${adult}` в конструкции `summary['${MEN}${soc}${adult}${WORK_NO}']:0,`. Как такое можно провернуть?

Comment: Начать можно с того, что у тебя просто жуть, а не данные. Если данные начать хранить более осмысленно - тогда и выводить результат можно любой.

Comment: @ksa, это ОФИГЕННАЯ модель организации данных, если Вы ее не понимаете и не можете понять ее смысла... Ну, это вовсе не значит, что это нужно выбросить в топку...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение данной проблемы оказалось довольно простым, но трудоемким.
Для начала, нам понаботься еще одна константа, которая будет обозначать вариант без выбора, я назвал ее `ALL`.

Далее необходимо было привести к единому виду обьект `summary`, чтобы по нему можно было делать перебор по нужному количеству переменных.

Например, если у нас 4 поля `select`, то и количество полей в ключе обьекта `summary` должно быть 4 штуки.

```
  [`${MEN}${ALL}${ALL}${ALL}`]:0,//0ХХХ
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ALL}${ALL}`]:0,//00ХХ
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_YES}${ALL}`]:0,//001Х
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_NO}${ALL}`]:0,//000Х
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_YES}${WORK_YES}`]:0,//0011
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_YES}${WORK_NO}`]:0,//0010
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_NO}${WORK_YES}`]:0,//0001
  [`${MEN}${SLAVE}${ADULT_NO}${WORK_NO}`]:0,//0000
```

Все поля, которые исключаются из поиска, получают значение `ALL`. Таким образом, мы получаем единый стандарт для всех переменных. Так, если нам нужны "мужчины", то мы выбираем не `['${MEN}']:0,` а   `['${MEN}${ALL}${ALL}${ALL}']:0,`.

Дальше уже дело техники.

Мы делаем небольшую функцию, которая считывает значения из наших элементов `select` и формирует из них "переменную", которая соответсвует конкретному ключу обьекта `summary`, после чего, полученный итог, публикуем в нужном месте:

```
  let func = function(e) {
    let gen = document.querySelector('[name="Gender"]').value
    let soc = document.querySelector('[name="Social status"]').value
    let ad = document.querySelector('[name="Adult"]').value
    let work = document.querySelector('[name="Work"]').value
    document.getElementById('qualityTotal').innerText = summary[`${gen}${soc}${ad}${work}`]
  }
  document.getElementById('info_workers').addEventListener("change", func, false)
```

На саму таблицу вешаем `addEventListener`, чтобы он отслеживал изменения элементов `select`.

Если возник вопрос, почему на таблицу, а не, например, на элементы `select`, поясняю: проблема в том, что `select`-элементов в таблице может быть много, а значит, чтобы отслеживать изменения на всех элементах, данную функцию нужно будет подцепить на все элементы. Это лишний код, лишние проверки и лишняя загрузка памяти.

Поэтому, намного проще установить `addEventListener` на элемент, который будет родителем для всех элементов `select`.

Как итог, получаем таблицу, где можно выбрать нужные параметры и узнать значения, которые хранятся в них без лишних телодвижений.

===============================================

P.S. Может показаться, что такая система организации данных слишком не рациональна, однако, в конечном итоге, она позволила очень сильно и довольно легко упростить сам исполняющий код программы. Мне потребовалось всего одна строчка кода, чтобы найти нужный элемент и вывести его, если бы данные были организованы по иному принципу, данная задача потребовала куда-более сложных программных решений.

Однако недостаток этого подхода так же вполне очевиден, так как в списке возможных вариантов обьекта `summary` пришлось учесть вообще все возможные варианты, которые, возможно, никогда и не понадобятся, однако для корректности работы программы они должны были быть учтены. Соответственно, чем больше возможных вариантов, тем более обширным будет обьект `summary`, поэтому, такой вариант уместен, если возможных вариантов не сильно много, если же их, скажем, больше 100, то есть смысл рассмотреть другие варианты решения данной проблемы.